# My Python V2 Azure Function is not showing up in my Azure Portal

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use the new Python Azure Function V2 method and for some reason it will not show up in the portal. I have "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing" set in my local settings and I have source control enable so I am deploying through Github

My file structure:

```
azure_app
 - monitoring_weekly
    - function_app.py
    - file1.py
    - file2.py
    - file3.py
    - file4.py
    - file5.py
 - host.json
 - requirements.txt
```

Function_app.py

```
import azure.functions as func
import os
import datetime
import logging
import sys
import importlib.util

# Azure function timer. To alter timer cadence see function.json file
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="monitoring_weekly")
@app.schedule(schedule="0 5 * * 1", 
              arg_name="mytimer",
              run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=True) 

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
        
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)


def run_script(script_name):
    script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f'{script_name}')

    s = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(script_name, script_path)
    m = importlib.util.module_from_spec(s)
    sys.modules[s.name] = m
    s.loader.exec_module(m)

    
def batch_execution(file_list):

    exceptions = [] #store errors

    for file in file_list:
        try:
            run_script(file)
        except Exception as e:
            exceptions.append(e)
        else: 
            print('Success')

    return exceptions

#list of scripts running in function, if adding new script add to list.
file_list = ['file1.py',
        'file2.py',
        'file3.py',
        'file4.py',
        'file5.py']

batch_execution(file_list)
```

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

requirements.txt

```
azure-functions
sqlalchemy
snowflake-sqlalchemy
snowflake-connector-python
sparkpost
tabulate
pandas


runtime version: 4.24.4.4
```

[image]

Comment: What do you see in github actions?

Comment: @zolty13 GitHub actions say that it is successfully building and deploying. If I look in the 'app files' section of the portal I can find my updated host file but it looks like for some reason azure isn't detecting my timer trigger. I've also tested with a generic http trigger and still no luck

Comment: sorry man I need more data to help you

Comment: Anything that I can provide?

Answer (score 2):

***I reproduced your requirement in my environment by creating Python v2 function with your code and deployed to Azure.***

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

- Refer [MSDOC](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model/ba-p/3665168) for difference in folder structure between `Python V1 and V2`:

[image]

**Local Response:**

[image]

- **Application Settings in `Azure Function=>Settings=>Environment variables(or)configuration`:**

[image]

**My GitHub Workflow to deploy python v2 function to Azure using GitHub actions:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - <webapp_name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' 
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
        
      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            . 
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: '<webapp_name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_C0XXXXXXXXXXX}}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
```

**Deployed functionapp successfully:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

[image]

**Portal response:**

[image]